# Webhook not trigering

Tags: webhooks, dropbox

I have an account on `dropbox` - **axxxxh@yahoo.com** in which I have a root folder (say `myFolder`). Inside `myFolder` I have sub folders `sub1`, `sub2`, etc. I wanted to configure webhook so that on file change webhook is being called.

In my app console, I have 1 development user (which I guess is only me, see screenshot)
[image]

---

I have also verified the webhook (see screenshot) as told in [webhook tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks#tutorial). It says that "if there are no accounts connected to your app, your webhook URI will not receive any webhook notifications." Which is not the case I guess. After all of this, when I change files inside subfolders, nothing is triggering my webhook. Am I missing something here?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and I was able to successfully register a webhook URI with Dropbox and then receive webhook notifications when making changes in an account connected to the app.

I suggest checking the following to make sure:

- you've registered the webhook URI on the same app as the one you've connected to the account
- you're making changes in the same account as the one connected to the app
- if the app only has "app folder" [access](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions), you're making changes inside the special app folder for the app (by default under "/Apps" for accounts with the English locale)
- if the app is "scoped", the connected account has authorized the "files.metadata.read" scope to the app (see ["Requesting the appropriate scope for your app"](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks))
- you're checking the logs for the same URI as you've registered as the webhook URI